# Закрытие формы после отправки

Tags: php, javascript, плагин

Есть форма, которая обрабатывается плагином Remodal, работает нормально и сообщения отсылает, вот только как сделать, чтобы после отправки сообщения она закрывалась, а не висела открытой? В плагине код js минимизирован и разобраться очень сложно что и где. Могу кинуть плагин, какой он есть. Кто подскажет как? Может в php файл нужно что-то дописать?

Comment: Вы же его вызываете как то? У него же есть API?

Comment: плагин? вот что в шапке написано

Comment: /*
 *  Remodal - v1.1.0
 *  Responsive, lightweight, fast, synchronized with CSS animations, fully customizable modal window plugin with declarative configuration and hash tracking.
 *  http://vodkabears.github.io/remodal/
 *
 *  Made by Ilya Makarov
 *  Under MIT License
 */

Comment: После того как ваша форма успешно отправила сообщение (видимо через AJAX), в блоке `success` используйте `object.close();`, где `object` это экземпляр Remodal, который вы создали

Comment: Хм, бро, подскажи, где и что нужно написать, я в js не силен.Там просто столько наворочено, что у меня глаз разбегается. КОд минимизирован и все на переменных.Это ты понял посмотрел на гите код?

Comment: вот та часть которая отправляет через ajax как я понял $.ajax({type:"POST",url:'https://..mail.php',data:formNm.serialize(),success:function(data){message.html(data);formTitle.css("display","none");setTimeout(function(){$('.formTitle').css("display","block");

Comment: Как вы вызываете Remodal? Начнем с этого

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70260/discussion-between-deniskins-and-daemonhk).

Comment: data-remodal-id="firstModal"
через id